# How to access a class function variable in a separate file?

Tags: php, function, class

I am wanting to access `$imageFileType` in a separate file. The file has been required in the separate file.

I have done this to access the classes' function before, but unsure how to go a step further to get a variable from the function.

```
$fu = new fileUpload();
$filename = $fu->upload();
```

Any ideas?

Code from the class.

class fileUpload
{

```
public function __construct()
{}
public function upload() {

    if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"])) {

        $file_count = count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
        $results = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

Full class:

```
class fileUpload
{

public function __construct()
{}
public function upload() {

    if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"])) {

        $file_count = count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
        $results = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
//          echo $file['uploadedFile']['name'][$index] . "\n";

            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
            $uploadOk = 1;
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
            if ($uploadOk == 0) {
                return 0;
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
            } else {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"][$i], $target_file)) {
                    $results[] = basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return $results;
```

Comment: You could have a property on the fileUpload class fileUpload::$imageFileType; which gets set in your upload loop, you might need to deal with it as an array as I see you're able to handle multiple files

Comment: I just added the full class in case it would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

class fileUpload {

    public $imageFileTypes = [];

    // your code

    public function getImageFileTypes()
    {
         return $this->imageFileTypes;
    }

    public function upload()
    {

        if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"])) {

        $file_count = count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);
        $results = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);

            // here's the important bit
            $this->imageFileTypes[] = $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        }

    // etc etc
}
```

Now in your other file

```
$fu = new fileUpload();
$filenames = $fu->upload();
$uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();
```

Hopefully you can take that idea and adapt it into your code

Comment: Thank you. When I tried to send the results via `file_put_contents`, the output is just a single 1. Any ideas? `$fu = new fileUpload();
  $filename = $fu->upload();
  $uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();
  file_put_contents('file_type_log', "\n[{$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')}]" . print_r($uploadedFileTypes), FILE_APPEND);`

Comment: `print_r($uploadedFileTypes, true)` the second parameter in print_r means return as a string, otherwise it returns a boolean which is where the 1 is coming from 

Comment: Perfect. That rendered the correct file type. Could you point me in the direction of how I can take it out of the following format and put it into a comma-separated list? `Array
(
    [0] => png
)`

Comment: instead of the `print_r` try `implode(', ', $uploadedFileTypes)`

Comment: Well, this is more for this: `$uploadedFileTypes = $fu->getImageFileTypes();` .... unless it is already doing it. I will be using the variable in a condition to check for certain file types.

Answer (score 0):

When you need specific data to be accessed outside classes, it's recommended to use getters and setters.

You can have something like this:

```
<?php
class FileUpload {
    private static $lastUploadedFileType;

    public function __construct() {}

    public function upload() {
        [...]
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        self::$lastUploadedFileType = $imageFileType;
        [...]
    }

    public static function getLastUploadedFileType() {
        return self::$lastUploadedFileType;
    }
}
```

And call it anywhere with:

```
<?php
FileUpload::getLastUploadedFileType();
```

PS.: I used static in the example because that way you won't need to instantiate an object.